# How to insert data in child table(Tb1) of parent table(Tb2) that is also the parent(Tb2) of child(Tb1) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am very new to MySQL, just started on it a few days ago. For my homework, the MySQL has its default set to MyISAM for simplicity's sake, and had me created a hospital example database for practice on MySQL.

But for my own personal purpose and some research that InnoDB actually enforces the FK compared to MyISAM, I switched the default to InnoDB and tried to recreate the same database I did for my homework with MyISAM.

And then the problem whacked me like a truck, my "ward" table is the following:

```
create table Ward
(Code varchar(1) primary key not null,
Name varchar(15) not null,
Consultant varchar(3) not null);

alter table ward
add foreign key (Consultant)
references Doctor(ID);
```

and my doctor table goes like this:

```
create table Doctor
(ID varchar(3) primary key not null,
Name varchar(15) not null,
Ward varchar(1) not null);

alter table doctor
add foreign key (Ward)
references Ward(Code);
```

After that, I tried entering data in either of the tables, and the following errors were given to me when I try to enter data into "ward" table and "doctor" table respectively:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`hospital`.`ward`, CONSTRAINT `ward_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`Consultant`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`ID`))
>
> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`hospital`.`doctor`, CONSTRAINT `doctor_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`Ward`) REFERENCES `ward` (`Code`))

How do I enter data into either of the tables?

Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably 'wrong' to have FKs going back and forth like that.

You can disable foreign keys while you create the tables.  But then you may have trouble with inserts -- one insert will find a FK violation since you have not done the other yet.

If you don't have loops in your FKs, then simply create the tables in the 'right' order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll do it that way then.

For extra information, however, does the FK loop like that in real life? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know; I don't use `FOREIGN KEYs`.  Instead I use indexes and make sure in my code that no "foreign key constraints" would be violated.